# Strpos() returning unexpected string

Tags: php, strpos

I for the life of me cannot figure out why this is not working.

```
$value="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p1";

$startvar="http://";
$endvar="/";

$start = strpos($value,$startvar);

$end = strpos($value,$endvar,$start) + 8;

$results = substr($value,$start,$end-$start);
echo $results;
```

No matter what I do it will always return the http:// which I do not want. I just want the www.google.com.  I'm using this in another area and there it's behaving exactly like I want.  I did get this to work if I use a numerical starting point and not $startvar but that won't necessarily work all the time.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.

Thanks
Bruce

Comment: Wouldn't strpos($value,$startvar); return 0 because the "http://" part of the URL starts at 0? That being said, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php.

Comment: What is your objective here? [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) may offer a better solution. If not using IIS you could use `$results = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: Or you could just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) `$results = str_replace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $value);`

Comment: I'm just doing some cleaning up of links to remove all the extraneous characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip over the whole `$startvar` token to get to the next bit of your string.  `strpos` returns the beginning of the match.

```
$start = strpos($value,$startvar) + strlen($startvar);
```

Although you will also need to make sure that `strpos` hasn't returned `false`, which it will do if `$startvar` is not found:

```
$pos = strpos($value, $startvar)
if ($pos !== false)
{
   $start = $pos + strlen($startvar)
   //... other steps here...
}
```

If your objective is simply to parse a URL, you can use the PHP function [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), which will make your life much easier.

Comment: Thanks steve. That makes sense.  What would make this different than the following  $start = strpos($content,'<div id="resultStats">');
 
$end = strpos($content,'</div>',$start) + 10;
 
$results = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);
That pulls just the portion between those tags and works perfectly? Am I missing a nuance here?   THanks again for the quick reply.

Comment: It will include the opening `<div` unless I'm misreading your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```php
$value="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p1";
list($a,$b,$c) = split('[/]',$value);

echo'<br/>a = ',$a;
echo'<br/>b = ',$b;
echo'<br/>c = ',$c;
```

You will find that `$c` is your answer.